# Symfony2 : dynamic search form

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to make a dynamic search form, usable by many entities. Everything works fine but I need to test all fields to check the type and his criteria : text => LIKE, choice => EQ, choice => IN (multiple =true)...
Do you have any idea to do that? thanks...

```
public function search($Type, $search, $container)
{
    $repository = $container->getDoctrine()->getRepository('prodCMDBBundle:'.$Type);

    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $queryBuilder->join('a.customers', 'p');

    foreach ($search['docs'] as $field => $value) {

        if ($repository->getClassMetadata('prodCMDBBundle:'.$Type)->hasField($field) && $value) {
            // ******** ??? Check my field type ??? ******/
            $queryBuilder ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('a.'.$field, ':a_'.$field))->setParameter('a_'.$field, $value);
        }
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery();
}
```